# Newly added child entries not showing on listing/parent page straight away

Tags: structure, cache, children

I am running into an odd issue where creating new child entries does not bust the cache of the parent page(s) that lists them.

This is the structure I am working with:
[image]

I am displaying the `Course` entries on the `Course Landing Pages` like so:

```
{% cache using key craft.request.path %}

  {% set currentPage = craft.entries.id(entry.id).first() %}

  {% set entries = craft.entries({
    type: 'course',
    descendantOf: currentPage,
    with: [
      ['courseThumbnail', {
        withTransforms: [
          { mode: 'crop', width: 800, height: 800, position: 'center-center', format: 'jpg' }
        ]
      }]
    ]
  }) %}

  {% for entry in entries %}
      {% include '_includes/_listing-item-course' with { featured : true } %}
  {% endfor %}

{% endcache %}
```

When I publish a new `Course` entry, the cache for the parent page(s) is not busted and the new entry will not show unless I move/drag into a new position. This seems to clear the cache and the new entry shows on the parent page(s).[image]

If I change the `craft.entries` call to **not include** the `descendantOf` part, so it looks like this:

```
 {% set entries = craft.entries({
    type: 'course',
    with: [
      ['courseThumbnail', {
        withTransforms: [
          { mode: 'crop', width: 800, height: 800, position: 'center-center', format: 'jpg' }
        ]
      }]
    ]
  }) %}
```

Then newly added `Course` entries will show up straight away on all the `Course Landing Pages`.

Why is that?

Comment: There is definitely something going on with the `descendantOf` parameter. If I set entries like this `{% set entries = craft.entries.type('course') %}`, new ones show up straight away when published. The moment I change it to this `{% set entries = craft.entries.type('course').descendantOf(entry) %}`, they won't show up unless I manually clear the cache or move the new entry’s position in the structure tree. Very odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/1667) – automatic cache busting currently doesn’t work when the `descendantOf` param is set to an actual element.

Unfortunately there’s no easy fix on Craft’s end, without a pretty drastic change to how cache busting works.

As a workaround, you can change your `descendantOf` param value to `currentPage.id` rather than just `currentPage`.

Comment: Thank you Brandon. I'm glad this is a known issue. However, using `entry.id` does not work for me either running version 2.6.2982. Any other workaround suggestions?

Comment: I added my workaround solution as an answer. If you/anyone knows of a more efficient/elegant way, do let me know :)

Comment: This also seems to apply when using entry.descendants or entry.getDescendants()?

Comment: And when using children()?

Comment: @TomDeSmet same

Answer (score 1):

Since using `descendantOf(currentPage.id)`, as Brandon suggested, didn't work, I have come up with this workaround solution:

```
{% set currentPageID = entry.id %}

{% set entries = craft.entries.type('course') %}

{# only display entries that have currentPage as an ancestor #}
{% for entry in entries if currentPageID in entry.getAncestors().ids() %}
  {% include '_includes/_listing-item-course' with { featured : true } %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a better solution. I'm using the [CacheFlag](https://github.com/mmikkel/CacheFlag-Craft) plugin which solves this problem. And it's very easy to add to existing code.